# ubuntu freeze when start gimp

Tags: gimp

Every time I try to start gimp, the whole system will freeze and the  keyboard and mouse will not work, even pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> does nothing; I can only hold the power button and shut my laptop down forcefully.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and the GIMP was installed using `apt`.

Comment: It is not an answer, but I moved from Gimp to [Photopea.com](https://www.Photopea.com). It can work with my current XCF files :)

Comment: I think it's a bug in GIMP.  I've had nearly the same problem from the start in GIMP 2.6.8, running on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with GNOME 2.30.2 on an IBM ThinkCentre machine, except it happens after editing an image for a while.  The only thing I can do is save frequently while working with GIMP so I can re-open the file after rebooting the system and continue, losing just a little of my work.  Other programs don't behave that way, so I think my hardware is OK.  I don't know if a remote login (rlogin)  from another terminal could clear the hang without reboot.

Comment: I think the cause of that problem is the graphic driver, my GIMP works fine after the removal of  proprietory  Driver(AMD Radeon  R7  260).